# .Net Core Image Manipulation (Crop & Resize) / File Handling

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, crop, image-resizing, image-manipulation

I have spent the last 5 hours trying to find a feasible way to accomplish what seems to me quite an easy task if it was a previous version of the .NET family that I was working with:

1. Uploading a picture
2. Resizing & Cropping the picture
3. Saving the new picture into a directory

I have come accross to couple of libraries that are either in pre-release stage or in a not-complete stage.

Has anyone at all accomplished the above tasks without specifically including the System.Drawing namespace and/or adding a dependency for an earlier version of the .NET framework?

### UPDATE on 08 / 08 / 2016

I ended up using System.Drawing something which is very annoying and disappointing. If you are developing a software used by thousands of developers, and if all these developers are relying on the components of this software, I believe, one cannot just come up with a new version, "sweet talk" about it during the conferences to show off your public speaking skills rather than giving a shit about your work and on one hand proudly hold in high esteem of it, and on the other, strip away the mostly used and demanded portions of it.

I do understand and appreciate with great excitement myself - of the new era of .net with the core framework - being a loyal asp dev since the first days of classic asp - however, to me, it is just an uncomplete product causing more frustrations and dissappointment than pleasure. When there are millions of websites in today's content-driven world, completely relying on content management, you can't just come up and say, "Hey, I have this brilliant, techonology, leaner, faster blah blah" but errr, you will have some problems with "managing" your content..

It should not be forgotten that, although, MS (and us) is very excited about this new core framework, with now being open source etc, there are other languages and frameworks out there that are doing what MS is promising to do, for a very very long time now.

Comment: Uploading is well described in the documentation, but there is no out-of-the-box image library in .NET Core, maybe there are some 3rd party libraries though. And pre-release is the best you can get, considering .NET Core was released just a few weeks ago and most developers started porting their projects only after it hit RTM

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScriptService that I have mentioned below?

Comment: I don't want to spend time to figure out an alternative. I am angry because we are left to do so.. (I said alternative, if it was the "new" way of doing "something", then I would happily learn it.)

Answer (score 15):

**[ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp)**

#### **ImageSharp** is a new, fully featured, fully managed, cross-platform, 2D graphics API.

Designed to democratize image processing, ImageSharp brings you an incredibly powerful yet beautifully simple API.

Compared to `System.Drawing` we have been able to develop something much more flexible, easier to code against, and much, much less prone to memory leaks. Gone are system-wide process-locks; ImageSharp images are thread-safe and fully supported in web environments.

Built against .Net Standard 1.1 ImageSharp can be used in device, cloud, and embedded/IoT scenarios.

Comment: ImageSharp works, but it's far too slow - 13 seconds to resize an average-size image ...

Comment: In debug, 32bit mode because SIMD isn't supported in that environment yet and you couldn't be bothered to actually test properly, or reach out to me. Are you deliberately trolling my library?

Comment: @JamesSouth do you have any update on your progress? I see it's still marked as pre-release. Thansk

Comment: @Simon_Weaver beta4, rc targeted 2 months, hopefully v1 in 3.

Comment: I have implemened ImageSharp so it resizes images in a controller action, however when the URL is called in an <img src=""/> tag, the requests aren't cached in the browser like they are with static files. Is there a way to get these requests to cache so resized images are not downloaded each time? Or is there a way to implement ImageSharp for static image files like https://imageresizing.net/ can?

Comment: Hi @m.brookson, to the best of my knowledge _ImageSharp_ support [In memory caching](https://andrewlock.net/using-imagesharp-to-resize-images-in-asp-net-core-part-3-caching/) and [saving on disk](https://andrewlock.net/using-imagesharp-to-resize-images-in-asp-net-core-part-4-saving-to-disk/) as well.

Comment: imagesharp is still in beta. nuget doesn't provide the latest builds, as it has issues with basic scaling, which are only solved in development versions. using SkiaSharp now, which is fully supported and documented by Microsoft.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Microsoft ASP.NET Core JavaScript Services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) to invoke arbitrary NPM packages at runtime from .NET code which means you can choose any npm package that provide image scaling and invoke it.

The following example shows how to use JavaScriptServices to resize image
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/samples/misc/NodeServicesExamples

Hope that Helps

Comment: In my opinion, until an official image processing library get's built or ported to .Net Core, this is the best answer, seeing as Node is already part of the design practices for ASP.Net Core Projects with front end resources.  Node has a plethora of packages for image manipulation.  You can even do facial recognition with OpenCv in Node.  Just write your image helper class in Node in a static Js File and invoke it from Core through JSS.

Comment: How is that .NET Core if it runs and requires NodeJS ?

Comment: @hossam barakat - do you have any recommendations for the best/most popular image manipulation NPM packages?

Comment: BTW. Looks like after you wrote this they actually replaced their image sample code with a charts sample - but this is just a demo of the 'connector' - here's the resize image sample https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/v1.0.x/samples/misc/NodeServicesExamples/Node/resizeImage.js

Answer (score 6):

[.NET Core Image Processing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/) blog post (January 19, 2017) compares 6 libraries:

- CoreCompat.System.Drawing
- ImageSharp
- Magick.NET (Win only)
- SkiaSharp
- FreeImage-dotnet-core
- MagicScaler

**Feb 26 update:** post was updated, two new packages added

Comment: Use SkiaSharp. CoreCompat is not thread-safe and incomplete, ImageSharp is way too slow, Magick.NET WinOnly, FreeImage has bugs, MagicScaler does only Image-Scaling.

Comment: Magick.NET is not win only, I use it on aspcore.

Comment: "ImageSharp is way too slow"... Here we go again.

Comment: Magick.NET is ready to use on Linux !! and easy to use... https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET

Answer (score 4):

To complete the @Hossam Barakat answer, you can use the [Microsoft ASP.NET Core JavaScript Services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) to invoke arbitrary NPM packages at runtime from .NET code which means you can choose any npm package that provide image scaling and invoke it.
The sample use the [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) module, which has a lot of dependecies. If you prefere, like me, to use [jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) which is pure javascript:

### Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
 ...
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Enable Node Services
        services.AddNodeServices();
...
    }
...
}
```

### ImageController.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace NodeServicesExamples.Controllers
{
    public class ResizeImageController : Controller
    {
        private const int MaxDimension = 1000;
        private static string[] AllowedMimeTypes = new[] { "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif" };

        private IHostingEnvironment _environment;
        private INodeServices _nodeServices;

        public ResizeImageController(IHostingEnvironment environment, INodeServices nodeServices)
        {
            _environment = environment;
            _nodeServices = nodeServices;
        }

        [Route("resize/{*imagePath}")]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 3600)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string imagePath, double maxWidth, double maxHeight)
        {
            // Validate incoming params
            if (maxWidth < 0 || maxHeight < 0 || maxWidth > MaxDimension || maxHeight > MaxDimension
                || (maxWidth + maxHeight) == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid dimensions");
            }

            var mimeType = GetContentType(imagePath);
            if (Array.IndexOf(AllowedMimeTypes, mimeType) < 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("Disallowed image format");
            }

            // Locate source image on disk
            var fileInfo = _environment.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(imagePath);
            if (!fileInfo.Exists)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var eTag = GenerateETag(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{fileInfo.LastModified.ToString("s")}-{fileInfo.Length}"));
            HttpContext.Response.Headers["ETag"] = eTag;

            var match = HttpContext.Request.Headers["If-None-Match"].FirstOrDefault();
            if (eTag == match)
            {
                return StatusCode(304);
            }

            // Invoke Node and pipe the result to the response
            var imageStream = await _nodeServices.InvokeAsync<Stream>(
                "./Node/resizeImage",
                fileInfo.PhysicalPath,
                mimeType,
                maxWidth,
                maxHeight);

            return File(imageStream, mimeType, fileInfo.Name);
        }

        private string GetContentType(string path)
        {
            string result;
            return new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(path, out result) ? result : null;
        }

        private string GenerateETag(byte[] data)
        {
            string ret = string.Empty;

            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                var hash = md5.ComputeHash(data);
                string hex = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
                ret = hex.Replace("-", "");
            }

            return ret;
        }

    }
}
```

### Node\resizeImage.js

```
var jimp = require("jimp");

module.exports = function (result, physicalPath, mimeType, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
    // Invoke the 'jimp' NPM module, and have it pipe the resulting image data back to .NET
    jimp.read(physicalPath).then(function (file) {
        var width = maxWidth || jimp.AUTO;
        var height = maxHeight || jimp.AUTO;
        file.resize(maxWidth, height)
             .getBuffer(mimeType, function (err, buffer) {
                 var stream = result.stream;
                 stream.write(buffer);
                 stream.end();
             });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
};
```

install jimp: `npm install jimp --save`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no, not yet. Most if not all current libraries rely on System.Drawing. If you need this now, I would go that route and add System.Drawing.

The .NET team is currently working through the features that are missing on the Core 1.0 stack, but this one isn't high enough on their priority list: [Link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/issues/86#issuecomment-158459437)

This is a library to watch as they're getting very close to a releasable API without System.Drawing. : [ImageSharp](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp)

Answer (score 0):

use SkiSharp, it is on the official microsoft documentation also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp?view=skiasharp-1.68.0